# How to scale game with orthographic camera correctly?

Tags: unity, mobile, scale

During porting to android I encountered that the game does not fit on the screen in portrait mode. It uses an orthographic camera. How could I scale to game to fit the screen in portrait mode?

[image: landscape]
[image: portrait]

Comment: You'll have to define for use what "correct" scaling looks like for your game, compared to what you're getting now. There's a lot of ways we might try to scale/frame a game to work in a different orientation, depending on what your gameplay and visual style demands.

Comment: The game is simply doesn't fit on the screen. With correct scaling I mean that the game is fully visible.

Comment: What does "fully visible" look like for your game? Include examples in your question to make sure you get accurate, applicable answers.

Comment: I think with the current description the problem should be already understandable, but I will include screen shots.

Comment: You can change the "zoom factor" by using the orthographic camera's `size` (in editor) or `orthographicSize` (in code) parameter. You can get the aspect ratio (with/height) from the `aspect` variable on the same camera.

Comment: And how should that solve my problem?

Comment: It sounds like you want to add letterboxing bars above and below the game scene, shrinking the vertical height until the horizontal fits. You can find a script that will do that here: [(Unity Android) How to force keep the aspect ratio and specific resolution without stretching the output screen view?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/144575/unity-android-how-to-force-keep-the-aspect-ratio-and-specific-resolution-witho)