# Keeping over-shoulder camera view consistent at different screen resolutions

Tags: unity, c#

I have a player GameObject.
There is a character attached to it and a camera (both are children of the player GameObject).

The over-shoulder camera is positioned nicely. 
The player should appear on the left edge of the screen.

Now when I change the viewport / screen size and make it larger, the camera doesn't keep it's view. I can see in the Inspector that the camera's view changes.

I don't understand in which way it does that.

What would I need to do to keep the player always on the left edge, no matter what the screen resolution is?

Thank you.

- The upper image shows how I have planned / developed the camera view. This is what the camera view should look like.
- The lower image shows how the camera changes at larger viewport.

[image]

Comment: Unity preserves the view settings along the vertical axis, and expands/contracts the horizontal axis in proportion to the aspect ratio of the screen. If you want the opposite, or something in between, you can dynamically adjust the camera's vertical FoV in response to the aspect ratio of the screen/window.

Comment: Hint: fov is an angle, but screen.width is a length. You'll need a little trigonometry [Fortunately we have existing answers that cover that](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/167332/39518). :)

Comment: Your script totally fixed my problem, thank you very much. In fact, my question is a perfect duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a way to make it work! I've closed the question as a duplicate based on your comment. If you later find the existing answer doesn't quite cover what you need, please feel free to edit this question to clarify what you need and we can re-open it for new answers.