# How to stop Sprites from stretching on Mobile with different aspect ratio

Tags: unity, mobile, aspect-ratio

On Unity 2020.3.24f1:

- I created a 2D Core Project and changed to build on any Android
  device.
- Added a simple 2D Circle Sprite to my Scene.

**The Problem:**

I want my Game to run in 9:16 aspect ratio all the time. If the device screen has another aspect ratio letterboxing will do fine.
But running the game on my Redmi Note 10 with screen dimensions of 1080x2400 stretches the circle vertically.

[image: Display on Device]

I tried [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/144575/how-to-force-keep-the-aspect-ratio-and-specific-resolution-without-stretching-th/144578#144578) script which is basically the same as the script on [this](http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.com/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html) site.
When I use 9:16 aspect ratio (in the script) no letterboxes are appearing. But when I change to 16:9 (in the script) with my device being in portrait mode there are letterboxes but the circle is still stretched.

[image: Widescreen]

I searched the web for around 4 hours tried everything I found and checked every option in the project settings but can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a wrong understanding of how Unity Remote 5 works.
When running the game in the editor Unity will use (as usual) the resolution/aspect ratio set in the Game panel of the editor then just mirror it to the connected device.
So adding a custom resolutio/aspect ratio with the same dimensions as the device will fix this problem.